# Aumentar um index até determinado número e depois diminuir até zerar com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer um script em `jquery` para aumentar um index até determinado número e depois diminuir um por um até zerar.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma para aumentar mas gostaria que quando chegasse no 5 ele diminuísse até zerar.

```
var index = 0;

setInterval(function ()
{
    teste();

}, 10000, true );

function teste()
{
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa de uma variável de controle indicando se é para incrementar ou decrementar, ou então usar alguma aritmética modular:

**Usando uma variável de controle:**

```
var index = 0;
var inc = +1;

var handle = setInterval(teste, 10000, true); // como o @bfavaretto indicou!

function teste()
{
    if (index == 5)
        inc = -1;

    index += inc;

    if (index == 0)
        clearInterval(handle);
}
```

Comment: Verdade, minha resposta (removida) estava falida.

Comment: Realmente, ela iria ficar alternando entre 4 e 5 no final... aliás eu não tinha percebido a função chamando outra função diretamente. Vou melhorar isso nessa resposta!

Comment: Boa solução `+1`

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai mais uma ideia, usando um objeto para guardar o valor do index e também a direcao; porque não ví a pergunta a tempo e sem desprestígio para a [resposta do Miguel Angelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12296/129) que já estava aceite quando coloquei a minha.

```
var index = {    // um objeto para guardar ...
    valor: 0,    // o valor inicial e que vai mudar
    direcao: ,   // a direccao, se sobe (1) ou desce (0)
    maximo: 5    // o máximo que pode atingir
};

var contador = setInterval(teste, 10000);

function teste() {
    // usar o valor
    console.log(index.valor);

    index.direcao ? index.valor++ : index.valor--;
    if(index.valor == index.maximo) index.direcao = !index.direcao;
    if (!index.direcao && index.valor < 0) clearInterval(contador);

}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MftY/1/)